# How to create internal frames in an overlay style, without modifying the underlying interface?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jinternalframe

/* JDialog is the answer */ As I see there are 2 ways to add additional windows, use JDialog, but in those you can't put containers. Or use JInternalFrames with a specific container like JDesktopPane, but for that you have to convert all the rest of the interface to be of internal frames too. What is the lightest way to add JInternalFrame-like windows with doing the least possible number of modifications to the underlying layout?

Comment: Otherwise I don't think that your question is specific enough to be answerable as it's quite a bit vague. Modifications to what underlying layout? If you want the best quickest help, you'll want us to fully understand your problem quickly, and to that end, consider creating and posting a minimal program that compiles and runs and shows us what general structure you have and what you're trying to do, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you tell me how to acquire the "contentPane" of the JDialog then? I haven't found an option to put containers in them yet. You would already answer my question.

Comment: You call `getContentPane()` on your JDialog instance, just the same as you would on a JFrame. The JDialog API would show you all the methods that JDialog has available to it, and I highly recommend that you have a look there.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now. I underrated JDialogs by Oracle's tutorial on it. JDialogs is the answer, although I could still imagine a transition between this and JInternalFrames, that keeps its overlaying and hierarchically independent style, while being able to be iconified.

Comment: Shoot, you can put an entire GUI into a JOptionPane if you need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDialog's have contentPanes just like JFrames, and any component that you can place into a JFrame can be placed into a JDialog.  For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogEg {
   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      MainPanelGen mainPanelGen = new MainPanelGen();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DialogEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanelGen.getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }

}

class MainPanelGen {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton btn = new JButton(new BtnActn());
   private JDialog dialog;
   private DialogPanel dialogPanel = new DialogPanel();

   public MainPanelGen() {
      mainPanel.add(field);
      mainPanel.add(btn);

      field.setEditable(false);
      field.setFocusable(false);
   }

   public JPanel getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private class BtnActn extends AbstractAction {
      BtnActn() {
         super("Button");
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         if (dialog == null) {
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
            if (win != null) {
               dialog = new JDialog(win, "My Dialog",
                     Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
               dialog.getContentPane().add(dialogPanel);
               dialog.pack();
               dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
         }
         dialog.setVisible(true); // here the modal dialog takes over
         System.out.println   (dialogPanel.getFieldText());
         field.setText(dialogPanel.getFieldText());
      }
   }
}

class DialogPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton exitBtn = new JButton(new ExitBtnAxn("Exit"));

   public DialogPanel() {
      add(field);
      add(exitBtn);
   }

   public String getFieldText() {
      return field.getText();
   }

   private class ExitBtnAxn extends AbstractAction {

      public ExitBtnAxn(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(DialogPanel.this);
         if (win != null) {
            win.dispose();
         }
      }
   }
}
```